# Python2 poor performance in simple math operations

Tags: java, python, performance, math

I am trying to do a small variation of euclidean distance (I am fully aware that that is not euclidean formula) for color quantization from RGB values to a 16 color palette. I have no problems with code, but performance in python is over 25 times slower than Java.

Main method in python looks like this:

```
def getBaseColor(rValue=128, gValue=128, bValue=128):
 allDistances=[450]*16
 for x in range(0,16):
  valoresColor = coloresWeb[x]
  allDistances[x]= (abs(valoresColor[0]-rValue) + abs(valoresColor[1]-gValue) + abs(valoresColor[2]-bValue))
 return allDistances.index(min(allDistances))
```

I did small benchmark tests (1M operations) and Java is 25 times faster than Python (2.7.9). Using pypy helps a lot, but still very far from Java.

> Python 2: ~5.2s
>
> Java: ~0.2s
>
> pypy: ~ 0.6s

**My question is:
Am I doing something wrong with python, or it is just super slow by nature?.**
This is a process that needs to be run hundred of million of times, and no, this is not image processing (although it looks like).

**Fully functional minimal codes are provided [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6kw32y0o8m389nl/pyVsJava.rar?dl=0) for Python and Java.**

Comment: Slow by nature. I believe you could speed it up a lot by using numpy.

Comment: @e4c5 I do not get it... how is that? for (int i=0;i<1000000;i++) FindNearestColor(134,234,43);

Comment: @nxgtrturbo oops sorry misread the java code

Comment: @amadan oops sorry misread the java code

Comment: @Amadan Do you mean basic things such as np.sum([a, b]) instead of a+b?

Comment: No, I mean calculating all 1M datums at the same time.

Comment: Remember that Python is late bound, so evaluating indices, for example, is not as fast as you might hope when run in a tight loop.

Comment: One huge thing you're missing is that Python does all its work with dynamically looked up names (no compile time binding like in Java), and its integer math is arbitrary precision, using wrapper objects instead of machine primitives. `numpy` can move more work to machine primitives, but a more accurate comparison would be to have Java do all the work using `java.math.BigInteger`; it will probably still be a little faster, but not by much. Heck, for that matter, caching `abs` to a local name might save non-trivial time; add `_abs = abs` to the top of the function; use `_abs` instead of `abs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With NumPy, calculating all million points at the same time:

```
import time
import numpy as np

webColours = np.array([
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,128],
    [0,128,0],
    [0,128,128],
    [128,0,0],
    [128,0,128],
    [128,128,0],
    [192,192,192],
    [128,128,128],
    [0,0,255],
    [0,255,0],
    [0,255,255],
    [255,0,0],
    [255,0,255],
    [255,255,0],
    [255,255,255]
])

def getBaseColours(colours):
    # colours is 1000000x3
    # set up a distances array (16x1000000)
    distances = np.zeros((16, np.size(colours, 0)))
    for colour in xrange(16):
        # calculate distance of each input colour to this webColour
        distances[colour] = np.sum(abs(colours - webColours[colour]), 1)
    # which of 16 distances is the least for each of 1000000 colours
    return np.argmin(distances, 0)

startTime = time.time()
colour = np.array([134,234,43])
colours = np.tile(colour, (1000000, 1))
getBaseColours(colours)
print "Time: " + str(time.time()-startTime)
```

Time: 0.9s on my system (where your Python code executes in 9s). Also, I'm a newbie at NumPy, so possibly the code could be optimised even further.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. However, of course it makes no sense to calculate the same color 1M times, it was coded that way just to show the performance issue, in real scenario, you can not know how many (or which ones) colors you will get (could be billions), so I am not so sure of the improvement. pypy improves the performance 10x times as well, without changing any in the code.

Comment: There should be no speed difference between 1M of same colour and 1M of different colours. If you are asking how to make things in Python fast, the answer is to offload as much as possible on numpy. If you are okay with switching to a compiled language, then do that - standard Python will never be able to compare.

Comment: Oh yes, I understand there is no difference between 1M same color vs 1M different colors, my point is, I am not so sure how feasible would be to do that with 10 billion items at the same time. But indeed I think I will stick with Java or just use pypy. Thanks a lot for your time and code, really appreciated.

Comment: With 10B it would probably blow through the memory, so you would need to do it in chunks; the idea would be to make the chunks big enough that you spend as much time in numpy (and as little in Python), but small enough that you can do it without having Python start swapping out memory. You would also benefit from allocating `distances` outside of the loop, so you allocate it only once. Still, I am not saying this is the best approach, just the best one if you select to use Python.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want to find a nearest neighbor for color quantization, you don't actually need to to calculate all the distances the way you are doing. In particular, using a [KDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) in this case would  be much more efficient.

Otherwise, as others have noted you get a slow results for Python because such operations would not normally be performed in pure Python. The default approach would be to use Numpy, and in this case this can also be speed up using a specialized function from Scipy (see [scipy.spatial.distance](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist) or better in this case [`scipy.spatial.cKDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html)). Finally if that is still not good enough, you can use Cython, Pypy, etc.

Comment: Very nice. I was almost sure something like this existed in SciPy, but I've never used it.